# git status showing two files modified after rename due to case

Tags: git, case-sensitive, case-insensitive

Using git, I apparently didn't use the proper approach when renaming files based on case sensitive file names on my Mac.

### Here is a simulation of the situation I'm in currently and am unsure how to get out of...

Create the repo and add a sample file:

```
git init
touch Foo.js
git add .
git commit -m 'adding Foo.js'
```

How I 'renamed' file (but should have used `git mv...` instead :( )

```
mv Foo.js foo.js
git status
```

Git status didn't show any changes so I updated the `core.ignorecase` property

```
git config core.ignorecase false
git status
```

Now it shows that I need to add foo.js.

```
git add foo.js
git status
git commit -m 'renaming Foo.js to foo.js'
```

Now if I try to edit `foo.js`

```
vim foo.js <-- edit foo.js
git status

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   Foo.js
    modified:   foo.js
```

If I try to `git rm Foo.js` it also is trying to delete my `foo.js` file as well.

My current `git --version` is `2.1.2`

### Any thoughts on how I fix things so `Foo.js` is gone and I only have `foo.js`?

Comment: In step 2 after doing `mv Foo.js foo.js` didn't `git status` show you that `Foo.js` is deleted?

Comment: No when I `git status` after the mv - I get nothing was deleted - but when I set `git config core.ignorecase false` I only see the file `foo.js` needs to be added (and `Foo.js` does not show up anywhere).

Comment: Are you under Windows or a Unix platform ?

Comment: on a Mac (which is a case-insinsitive os) - also noted in the first line of the question :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use 'git revert' on that commit where you included the renamed version of the file.
Then you can [properly] rename the file - as you indicated in your description - and create a new commit.

Example of properly renaming the file:

```
git mv --force Foo.js foo.js
```

Answer (score 3):

Git 2.29 (Q4 2020) adds another way to deal with this case:

See [commit 087c616](https://github.com/git/git/commit/087c61677c358091692ac6ce1de00bbfc9affdb1), [commit 409f066](https://github.com/git/git/commit/409f066716598d5050c34b7bb0e6859940428dcf), [commit 5065ce4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5065ce412ef083a02288c1972ea3d07423cace0e) (20 Sep 2020) by [brian m. carlson (`bk2204`)](https://github.com/bk2204).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit c5a8f1e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c5a8f1efc03746fd6b6c71fef8e3a5c38ce4e2e8), 29 Sep 2020)</sup>

> ### [`docs`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/087c61677c358091692ac6ce1de00bbfc9affdb1): explain how to deal with files that are always modified
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: brian m. carlson</sup>

> Users frequently have problems where two filenames differ only in case, causing one of those files to show up consistently as being modified. Let's add a FAQ entry that explains how to deal with that.
>
> In addition, let's explain another common case where files are consistently modified, which is when files using a smudge or clean filter have not been run through that filter.
> Explain the way to fix this as well.

`gitfaq` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/087c61677c358091692ac6ce1de00bbfc9affdb1/Documentation/gitfaq.txt#L366-L398):

> ### `Why do I have a file that's always modified?`
>
> Internally, Git always stores file names as sequences of bytes and doesn't
> perform any encoding or case folding.
>
> However, Windows and macOS by default
> both perform case folding on file names.
> As a result, it's possible to end up
> with multiple files or directories whose names differ only in case.
>
> Git can
> handle this just fine, but the file system can store only one of these files,
> so when Git reads the other file to see its contents, it looks modified.
>
> It's best to remove one of the files such that you only have one file.  You can
> do this with commands like the following (assuming two files `AFile.txt` and
> `afile.txt`) on an otherwise clean working tree:
>
> ```sh
> $ git rm --cached AFile.txt
> $ git commit -m 'Remove files conflicting in case'
> $ git checkout .
> ```
>
> This avoids touching the disk, but removes the additional file.
> Your project
> may prefer to adopt a naming convention, such as all-lowercase names, to avoid
> this problem from occurring again; such a convention can be checked using a
> `pre-receive` hook or as part of a continuous integration (CI) system.
>
> It is also possible for perpetually modified files to occur on any platform if a
> smudge or clean filter is in use on your system but a file was previously
> committed without running the smudge or clean filter.
> To fix this, run the
> following on an otherwise clean working tree:
>
> ```sh
> $ git add --renormalize .
> ```

Comment: thanks, `git rm --cached AFile.txt` was the bit I was looking for, to get rid of the old filename